# Why won't React events fire?

Tags: javascript, paypal, reactjs, webpack, react-engine

I am creating an isomorphic app with Webpack, [React-Engine](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine), express using the [React-Engine example](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/tree/master/examples/webpack). I finally worked it out so the code renders properly but I've come across a new problem standard events are not firing. I click on the button and "clicked" should be written to the console, but it doesn't work. The code is in bundle.js, and I added a breakpoint on the function, but nothing is happening. This is not my first React app, but it is my first time using React-Engine so I am willing to bet it has something to do with the way I have uses React-Engine, and React-Router. The functions in public/index.js, which I presume is meant to load new view files, are never called in my project.
Can you see why my events won't fire?

**Server.js**

```
require('node-jsx').install();
var express = require('express'); // call express
var app = express(); // define our app using express
...
var renderer = require('react-engine');
...
var engine = renderer.server.create();
app.engine('.jsx', engine);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');    
app.set('view', renderer.expressView);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('app', {
    title: 'React Engine Express Sample App',
  });
});
```

**public/index.js**

```
var client = require('react-engine').client;
var Routes = require('./routes.jsx');
var AppHandler = require('./views/appHandler.jsx');

// boot options
var options = {
  routes: Routes,

  // supply a function that can be called
  // to resolve the file that was rendered.
  viewResolver: function(viewName) {
      console.log(viewName)
    return require('./views/' + viewName);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function onLoad() {
  client.boot(options);
});
```

**public/routes.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

var AppHandler = require('./views/appHandler.jsx');
console.log(AppHandler);
//var Account = require('./views/account.jsx');

var routes = module.exports = (
  <Router.Route path='/' handler={AppHandler}></Router.Route>
);
```

**public/views/appHandler.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var App = require('./app.jsx');

var AppHandler = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <App {...this.props} ></App>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AppHandler;
```

**public/views/app.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
module.exports = React.createClass({
    clicked: function () {
        console.log("clicked");
    },
    render: function render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <body>
                    {this.props.title}
                    <button onClick={this.clicked}>button</button>
                </body>
                <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
            </html>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: When you click the button does anything (e.g. an error) get logged to the console? And can you confirm that you do see the button?

Comment: I can see the button, I can see this.props.title. There is nothing logged to the console, and when I put a breakpoint on the function nothing happens.

Comment: To help with diagnosing the problem I highly recommend downloading Facebook's react [dev-tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

may i ask if you are using macbook, and use the touchpad?
i have get the same scenario while i use material-ui and react.
i found the click event is not fired because i use touchpad, a tap event fired actually.

So if you use the touchpad, you can add the following code to enable the touch event.

```
var React = require('react'),
injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

and then try again.

Comment: It would be wonderful if it was something so simple. I am using a macbook, and a touchpad but unfortunately your solution did not fix the issue. I even tried using `React.initializeTouchEvents(true);` but still nothing

Comment: @EasilyBaffled i have tried your code, and it works correctly.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to post screenshots, i put it here[link](http://www.lovelyjs.com/index.php/2015/09/09/code-and-result-screenshots/)

Answer (score 0):

i am stuck in same place, so i think there may be problem wit setup of project, maybe react-engine, or even the approach (which can be server side rendering - that's why you are getting page and events aren't rendered there to fire)

did you meantime solved your problem?

EDIT:
i found workaround, that actually can help. The key is to move scripts to client side
in **app.jsx** should be in render method that has libraries in header and calls run_script.js script

```
render: function() {
return (
  <div>
    <head>
      <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.7.js"></script>
      <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div>
      <div id="content" align="center"></div>
      <script type="text/babel" src="/run_script.js"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

and the **run_script.js** looks (in my case) like

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    test: "false"
  };
},
handleChange: function(event){
  this.setState({test: event.target.value});
},
render: function () {
  return (
    <div id="example">
      <input value={this.state.test} 
        onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({test: 'true'})} }
      />

      {this.state.test}
    </div>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

hope this helps